# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module for the node module "angular2-multiselect-dropdown "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

After updating the node module **angular2-multiselect-dropdown** from v3.2.1 to v4.0.0. Then while running angular built command, It gives "**ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module**" For info: Am using yarn PM. Please guide me on this.

I am using angular(v4), @angular/cli: 1.2.7, node-v8.2.1

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /Users/welcome/wed/project/gui/management/node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   '/Users/welcome/wed/project/gui/management/src'  @ ./src/main.ts
>   3:0-74  @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: Finally, I downgraded the package to v2.9.0 since I am standing in production deployment queue. It is working now.. Very eager to solve this issue.Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use ngx-multi-select-dropdown:

for later angular versions:

```
npm i ngx-multi-select-dropdown
```

Comment: Its like rewrite of all my changes. I want to solve this issue. thnks for suggestion.cheers